# Why does pythons slice indexing give counter intuitive results?

Tags: python, list, indexing

If I have a 2D list in python `Data` and I want to create a slice of that 2D list, where I select all the elements from the first index and a single on from the second.

eg.

```
Data = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[h,i,g]]
```

and I want the list;

```
raw_data = [b,e,i]
```

Why does doing something like;

```
raw_data = Data[:][1]
```

not give the desired output?
I have specified the whole first index and the 1 index for the second.
Instead I get the output that is;

```
raw_data = [d,e,f]
```

Which is what I would expect to get from;

```
raw_data = Data[1][:]

raw_data = [d,e,f]
```

So;

```
Data[1][:] = Data[:][1]
```

Which is not compatible with my mental model of how lists work in python.

Instead I have to use a loop to do it;

```
raw_data = []

for i in xrange(0,len(Data),1):
       raw_data.append(Data[i][1])
```

So my question is, can anyone explain why `Data[1][:] = Data[:][1]` ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: taking a full slice of the list makes a copy, so you are making an identical copy of the list then getting item `1` from it, or getting item `1` then making a copy of the result.

Comment: I assume you are coming from a programming language that has multidimentional lists that let you do this, if so try out `numpy` as it lets you do `Data[:, 1]` to get your desired result.

Comment: 'list[:]' is just a copy of whatever `list` is. Meaning that `data[:] == data` (ish) and `data[1] == data[1][:]`. So of course `data[1][:] == data[:][1]`

Comment: `list[:]` doesn't return a slice (object), it returns a (copy of the) list. So `list[:]` == `list` and `list[:][1]` == `list[1]` == `list[1][:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lst[:]` has no explicit start an no explicit end, so according to the Python documentation, it will return a copy of the list starting at the start and ending at the end of the list. In other words, it will return a copy of same list you have before. So:

```
>>> Data = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['h','i','g']]
>>> Data[:]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'g']]
```

So when you say `Data[:]`, that will evaluate to the same as a copy of `Data`, meaning that `Data[:][1]` essentially is just `Data[1]`, which is `[d,e,f]`

If you do it the other way:

```
>>> Data[1]
['d', 'e', 'f']
>>> Data[1][:]
['d', 'e', 'f']
```

You get the second element in data, `[d,e,f]`, then you use that same list slicing syntax as before to get that same list again.

To get what you want, I'd use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x[1] for x in Data]
['b', 'e', 'i']
```

Simple as that.

Comment: You literally beat me by 20s :D

Comment: you fail to mention that `l[:]` _creates a copy of the list_, not return the same list! While it doesn't matter for this case it could easily spread misconceptions about slices.

Comment: You're right, I should have been more explicit - probably doesn't matter now, but I edited it to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Python doesn't have two dimensional arrays, but it does allow for extensions to implement them. You have a list of lists, which is somewhat different.

The solution to your problem is to **use numpy** which does have a 2d array type. You can then say `data[:,1]`

Why your example doesn't work as you expect: `data[:]` means "a copy of `data`" and so `data[:][1]` means the index 1 element of the copy of `data`, which is `[d,e,f]`

Comment: A two dimensional numpy array is really just an array of arrays, there's not much difference at all. For his use case numpy really doesn't add anything.

Comment: @James lists and numpy arrays are implemented dramatically differently, accessing columns of an array is significantly easier `Data[:,1]` then multidimensional lists.

Comment: @James I tend to disagree, a numpy array is a multidimensional structure. Conceptually it is different from a list of lists. If you actually have a 2d array, and it contains data of a consistent type, then `data[:,1]` is shorter, easier to read and quicker than a comprehension.  If you actually have a list of lists (eg variable length rows, inconsistent types) then the comprehension is more natural.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious if you go through what's happening from left to right.

```
raw_data = Data[:]
```

will give you the entirety of Data, so the whole list of lists: `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[h,i,g]]`

```
raw_data = Data[:][1]
```

will then give you the element at index 1 in this list, which is `[d,e,f]`.

On the other hand, 
    raw_data = Data[1]
will return the element at position 1 in data, which is also `[d,e,f]`.

`[:]` on this object will again return itself in its entirety.

What you are trying to do is best done with a list comprehension, such as:

```
raw_data = [x[1] for x in Data]
```

This will give you list of all second elements in all lists in Data.